# Tsung : config error, aborting

Tags: linux, erlang, load-testing, tsung

I am getting this error when i run Tsung

```
Config Error, aborting ! {undef,
                         [{xmerl_scan,file,
                              ["/root/.tsung/tsung.xml",
                               [{fetch_path,["/usr/share/tsung/","./"]},
                                {validation,true}]]},
                          {ts_config,read,2},
                          {ts_config_server,handle_call,3},
                          {gen_server,handle_msg,5},
                          {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}
```

Does that means `xmerl_scan` function definition is missing?

How to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: undef -- The function cannot be found when evaluating a function call.

Comment: Hi Vishnu could you comment your post with the command line you use, and you .xml scenario ? Regards

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 10. The Tsung confing file -> http://codeshare.io/fE18j. The log file -> http://codeshare.io/jOSkn.

Comment: Did you install Tsung with the package or did you compile it ? If you compiled it you must have the package `erlang-xmerl` installed, check this.

Answer (score 0):

When you installed erlang what distribution did you use? If it's a redhat variety you can yum install erlang using the epel repo and it will install all possible options to resolve this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and was able to solve it based on comment from Rodolphe
Once I have erlang-xmerl it works without issues -- in my case I didn't have to rebuild tsung.